# Use enter key to send text to a rich text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am currently using winforms and I want to send the text from a textbox to a rich text box by pressing enter. Here is the code I currently have

```cs
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
          richTextBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
          e.Handled = true;
     }
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your code in sample app, and it works.

Comment: Weird, my code executes but when I enter text in the textbox and press enter nothing happens

Comment: Did you check your *.Designer.cs file to see if you are using correct variable names, etc. You may have multiple richtextboxes overlapping each other or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I checked. Nothing is overlapping

Comment: @Skantzy:      If you don't want to spend much time on this, you can try a workaround-Add a button, Set it's visible property to false and then make it the AcceptButton of the form. Then you can do anything with the button!!

Comment: You didn't wire the `textBox1_KeyDown` handler to any `KeyDown` event of any Control.

Answer (score 1):

Did you subscribe to the event `KeyDown`? You can add a break point in `textBox1_KeyDown` to check it.

If the break point is not triggered, you can delete `textBox1_KeyDown` and double click the `Button` to re-generate it. Then will subscribe to the event "KeyDown" automatically.

Another way is that you can subscribe to events through code.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown;
}
```